# Unwanted exception thrown by Collections

Tags: java, collections, java-8

From the `Collections.nCopies()` specifications:

> "Returns an immutable list consisting of n copies of the specified
>   object."

So form my understanding it's iterator must throw `UnsupportedOperationException`

However its iterator doesn't throw `UnsupportedOperationException` , but throws `IllegalStateException`

```
 public class Main {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            final List<String> c = Collections.nCopies(1, "copies");
            c.iterator().remove();
        }
    }
```

Why this is behaving like this ? Please help me understand this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception documentation of `Iterator.remove` says:

> **IllegalStateException** - if the next method has not yet been called, or
>   the remove method has already been called after the last call to the
>   next method

This is what is happening in your case. Testing your code, if I call `next` first, I get the expected `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
final List<String> c = Collections.nCopies(1, "a");
Iterator<String> iterator = c.iterator();

iterator.next();
iterator.remove(); //java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Comment: But I what if we did not call the next method first

Comment: @11223 Then perhaps an iterator is not what you want to use... `Iterator.remove` [*Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--)